# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse does not work. Test becomes stuck

Tags: c#, testing, windows-phone-8

I've been trying to use HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse but it becomes stuck after CountdownEvent.Wait() is called. Using HttpClient I am not encountering the problem

```
    private static CountdownEvent latch;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test001()
    {
        latch = new CountdownEvent(1);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Finish), request);

        latch.Wait();
    }

    private void Finish(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FINISH");
        latch.Signal();
    }
```

Comment: Is this `Test001` method called in the UI thread? If so, the `latch.Wait();` line blocks the UI thread which is the problem.

Comment: I am not really sure. To be honest I'm very new to Windows Development + this silverlight unit test framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem most likely comes from the fact that `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(...)` needs the UI thread at some point (not synchronously). I don't know why is it like that, but it is how it is.

In your case, the method `Test001()` is most likely called in the UI thread. On the `latch.Wait();` line it blocks the thread, and so the request can't actually be made and it never completes.

If you could invoke the `Test001()` method on non-UI thread, it should work. Can't help you much more than this, as I don't really know how that unit test framework works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this..

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test001()
{
    latch = new CountdownEvent(1);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Finish), request);

   await latch;
}
```